# Maven - run java and groovy tests

Tags: java, maven, groovy, command-line-interface, spock

When running
`mvn test`
Only java tests are run

I want to learn how to run all tests without IDE

Output (important part)

```
[INFO] --- gmavenplus-plugin:3.0.0:addTestSources (default) @ project ---

[INFO] --- swagger-codegen-maven-plugin:3.0.35:generate (generate-orchestrator) @ project ---
...
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ project ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ project ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 32 source files to ...project/target/classes
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ project ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory ...project/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ project ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to ...project/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gmavenplus-plugin:3.0.0:compileTests (default) @ project ---
[INFO] Using isolated classloader, without GMavenPlus classpath.
[INFO] Using Groovy 3.0.13 to perform compileTests.
[INFO] Parallel parsing disabled.
[INFO] Compiled 8 files.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ project ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running TestSuite
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.258 s - in TestSuite
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

tests tree (anonimized, but idea is there)

```
src/test/
├── groovy
│   └── com
│             └── project
│                   ├── ASampleTest.groovy
│                   ├── smoke
│                   │   ├── BlaTest.groovy
│                   │   └── utils
│                   │       └── Provider.groovy
│                   └── unit
│                       ├── BlaTest2.groovy
│                       └── BlaTest.groovy
├── java
│   └── com
│               └── project
│                   └── AppTests.java
```

And I know that only java tests run because AppTests.java has no tests:

```
@SpringBootTest
class AppTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>project</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2-M3-groovy-3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.2-M3-groovy-3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.13</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.35</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-orchestrator</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/openapi/geo_search_v4.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <language>java</language>
                            <modelPackage>com.sabre.zjwpit.geo.api</modelPackage>
                            <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                            <generateApis>false</generateApis>
                            <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                            <library>resttemplate</library>
                            <configOptions>
                                <dateLibrary>java8-localdatetime</dateLibrary>
                                <hideGenerationTimestamp>true</hideGenerationTimestamp>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                        <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
                        <version>1.30</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>addTestSources</goal>
                            <goal>compileTests</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Dplatform.environment=ci</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is a project I got and just cloned, I've tried in IntelliJ Run All tests and it doesn't work either. I can run all groovy test with IntelliJ. but I'm interested in running all tests from command line mainly for learning puposes.

Comment: _" I know that only java tests run because AppTests.java has no tests"_ You are wrong. `AppTests` actually has one test, it just happens to be doing nothing. It should be reported, but is not. I.e., not just the Spock tests are not running but the JUnit Java tests are not either. This tells you that there is something fundamentally wrong with your POM.

Comment: My question would be why using groovy based test instead of Java ... apart from that the spring boot version is a bit out of date ... https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support apart from that you should migrate to Spring Boot 3.X

Comment: Karl Heinz, because Spock is an order of magnitude nicer than JUnit, both for developers and the stakeholders they talk to. For more than ten years, as an agile coach I have introduced Spock to multiple teams, and all of them never looked back, once they were infected. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your effective POM shows that you use Surefire 2.22.2 by default. If you upgrade to a more recent version, it should work:

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <argLine>-Dplatform.environment=ci</argLine>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If now your Spock tests are running, but not your Spring Boot test, probably you imported the JUnit 4 class `org.junit.Test`, which is also on your classpath. Instead, you need `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` for JUnit 5:

```java
package com.project;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
class AppTests {
  @Test // Do *not* import org.junit.Test!
  void contextLoads() {}
}
```

Now, both the Java JUnit Jupiter tests and the Spock 2 tests should run on the same platform, i.e. JUnit 5.

---

**Update:** The reason that JUnit 4 is on your classpath is that you got it via `groovy-all`, which also pulls in `groovy-test`. Maybe next time either only depend on `groovy` + other modules that you really need, or explicitly exclude `groovy-test`. Then the IDE will no longer offer to import the wrong annotation. But it will still offer the TestNG `@Test` annotation, so maybe you want to exclude that, too, if you do not need it.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
  <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.18</version>
  <type>pom</type>
  <scope>test</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
      <artifactId>groovy-test</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
      <artifactId>groovy-testng</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```